# Jupyter stops printing after I reconnect to Kernel

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, jupyter

I have an azure vm

1. I connect to it via putty from my windows machine
2. I use screen to run the jupyter on my local browser (chrome) using `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 9999 --ip=*`
3. I do DNS:9999 in my notebook and i can access the vm
4. I run a neural network to train on it and track the progress using print statements
5. I close the local browser and reopen it to track the progress by reconnecting to vm using putty and then going DNS:9999
6. Notebook is fine and running but has stopped printing

what is weird is that sometimes it does resume printing the progress

Any suggestions?